# How to use a var to look up and change a Object Property

Tags: javascript, string, object, properties, var

I'm looking for a way to use a string as a lookup in an Object.
Here is my code:

```
$.extend(true, myOptions,{ series: {lines: {show: true} } } );
```

The **lines** property could also be one of these:

bars

points

I have created a form where you can choose between those three options
So the property **lines** need to be a **variable**

```
$.extend(true, myOptions,{ series: {VARIABLE: {show: true} } } );
```

*How do I do that?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object literals/[initialisers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) don't support using variables as keys. Any identifiers used on the left of a `:` will be taken just for their name.

So, you'll have to break it out into multiple steps and use [bracket notation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) to have a `VARIABLE` key.

```
var input = { series: {} };
input.series[VARIABLE] = { show: true };

$.extend(true, myOptions, input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is confusing, but if you want to access object properties with the name stored in variable you can do it like `obj[var]`.